Create directory only if not exists (.NET)
Is there a way to be sure that I am the one that created a directory in C#?
By default, Directory.CreateDirectory is essentially an UPSERT operation: if the directory doesn't exist, it is created, but if it does already exist, well that's just fine. As long as it exists on return, everybody is happy.
But, I intend to delete the subtree when I'm done with it, and I don't want to do that if I didn't create it in the first place. As far as I can tell, the only way to achieve this will be P/Invoke because with the managed API, I must test for existence separately and there will always be a race condition between Directory.Exists and Directory.CreateDirectory.
In the underlying platform API, though, the call to create a directory will return an error if it already exists (ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS from CreateDirectoryW on Windows, EEXIST from mkdir on POSIX systems).
Is there a managed way to create a directory but only if it doesn't exist in .NET?

Those methods try to create to whole path do you need that? You are mentioning POSIX so you try or must stay system independent?

For windows look at https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/e233b7b5b00d9b80f155cd484e246dfc24fdf801/src/libraries/Common/src/System/IO/FileSystem.DirectoryCreation.Windows.cs#L16-L141 and use only the parts you need and check if the other stuff you see there are irrelevant ;)

Oh, I can do P/Invoke no problem, I just prefer not to if I don't have to. But it seems like in this case I might have to. Sigh. :-P

I linked the source because there might be more to it then just calling the Win API. For example if you follow "Interop.Kernel32.CreateDirectory" you will see its not just the pinvoke call.

Thanks :-) I've done plenty of native Win32 development in C/C++ as well as C# work, so it's no big deal to call the function. I just don't want to create that dependency if there is a managed way to do it. I haven't seen one in this case, though. :-P

_with the managed API, I must test for existence separately and there will always be a race condition between Directory.Exists and Directory.CreateDirectory? Unfortunately, this post makes little sense. Why do you believe there is a race condition?

My process: do { index++; path = "/tmp/foobar-" + index; } while (Directory.Exists(path)); Directory.CreateDirectory(path); DoStuffWith(path); Directory.Delete(path, true); /**/ Now, while this is running, another process is also running. My process passes "/tmp/foobar-0" into Directory.Exists and gets false back. The other process creates "/tmp/foobar-0" thinking it owns it. My process passes "/tmp/foobar-0" into Directory.CreateDirectory. No error. My process uses the directory then deletes the subtree. The other process just had the rug yanked out from under it.

The idiomatic approach at the system API level is to try to create the directory and watch for ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS (Windows) or EEXIST (Linux). Then, if another process gets there first, I get an error and can try a different name. If I get there first, then the other process gets an error. Either way, the processes can both know if another process "claimed" that path already. But .NET doesn't expose this, and silently hides all errors in Directory.CreateDirectory.

From your description I'm GUESSING your real problem is how to safely delete the directory you created when multiple copies of your code are running concurrently.  One general approach is to create an independent service that all your concurrent program instances submit their create/delete requests to, so it can determine when none of them need it any longer. Assuming you don't have to worry about programs besides your own using the directory, your service will be the only one that can create/delete, so then there's no worry about races. For tasks/threads there are simpler methods of locking

Alternatively, and much simpler, if your concurrent processes don't actually need access to the SAME directory, you could just use Directory.CreateTempSubdirectory(), which will create a subdirectory with a unique/randomly named subdirectory for each process. Then each process can presumably delete their unique subdirectory whenever they want.

Is it a XY problem (as @RichK suspects)? Can you disclosure what's behind your question? What is a process which prevents you to create your lovely directory?

Mm, nope, I'm actually writing an automated test and it needs a temporary directory for the duration of a test, and I want the most direct way for it to be absolutely sure that it is only deleting its own files. I could simply give the directory a name based on a GUID or the current time in ticks, but these are hacks when the API provides a proper mechanism to detect and resolve collisions.

Directory.CreateTempSubdirectory() is the solution.

Cool :-) I looked up its implementation. On Windows, it's doing basically what I'm doing, calling CreateDirectory and looping if it ever returns ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS. Interestingly, POSIX actually contains a core function to do exactly this for you called mkdtemp, and the UNIX implementation of CreateTempSubdirectory uses this. You give it a template, it creates you a directory and returns the name. Nice. :-) This is the answer to this question.

Please append your code to the end of your post, not in the comments.

It should be obvious that your design is flawed. Also, unless you're from the future, computer programs don't think. Computer programs execute the instructions that you programmed it to. If there's a race condition or a deadlock then you failed in your design.

Wow. Them's fighting words. Also, they're highly-flawed fighting words. You might want to retract them, because other people reading this back-and-forth will be very confused by what you just wrote.

Them's fighting words: How so? Design flaws happen. It's not an issue unless one refuses to acknowledge the issue and correct it. You might want to retract them, because other people reading this back-and-forth will be very confused by what you just wrote: You could probably delete the entire post. It lacks a minimal reproducible example and makes little sense without it. This post will likely be removed by the moderators some day.

I really feel like you are fundamentally misunderstanding pretty much everything about this post and the associated discussions.

You're right, there's little that I understand about this post. If you click on my userid you'll notice that I don't have any questions, only answers which means that I read a lot of posts. Unfortunately, this post is missing a lot of relevant information.

It really isn't. On the one hand, you have OS APIs which universally have a function that creates a directory but only if it doesn't exist. They all return an error code if it already exists. Most of them explicitly document that you can loop if you need to ensure that you were the one that created the directory. UNIX provides functionality that does this for you with mkdtemp. Even .NET's Directory.CreateTempSubdirectory does exactly this for you. It's a convention. But it is impossible to implement/follow with Directory.CreateDirectory.

@rotabor's answer of creating a directory elsewhere and then using Directory.Move to try to put it into place has a gap in that "creating a directory elsewhere" has exactly the same race condition problem -- but .NET provides a function Directory.CreateTempSubdirectory that can plug that gap. First use Directory.CreateTempSubdirectory to establish a directory that you know you were the creator of, then use Directory.Move to move it the target path. That may fail, even if you checked Directory.Move beforehand, because of the possibility of some other process sneaking in ahead of you, and then you can try a different path and loop or handle it otherwise as needed.
Also, if you don't need a specific target path, just some path that you own, then you can simply use Directory.CreateTempSubdirectory and be done with it.

Create the directory somewhere else in the drive then use the Directory.Move method. It fails if the target directory exists.
This ensures you are the creator if Move didn't fail.
P. S. Directory.CreateTempSubdirectory creates the temporary directory in the current user's temporary directory and it isn`t the universal solution from the location of the directory point of view, but the best one in most cases.
From other side, the solution above with using the long enough random composed name resolve the task in practice. Also, the preposition what a process tries to create a directory everywhere (to prevent user's app to create its own directory) looks very far-fetched.

Technically speaking, there's still a race condition there, because that directory "somewhere else on the drive" isn't guaranteed to be yours. Guess you can give it a GUID for a name or something :-P Cool trick, thanks.

"somewhere else on the drive" isn't guaranteed to be yours" but guaranties to be yours in the target place as you requested.

Well sure, but suppose the code naively always creates /tmp/NewDirectory and then moves that into position. Now, if there's another process out there using the same path for its own purposes, then my process will steal its directory and move it somewhere else. There are plenty of ways to make it very unlikely for this to happen, but it's a gap in terms of provable correctness.

Do you need a practical result or perform a theoretical study?

I want to write code that is provably correct from the get-go so that there are no gaps. At this point in time, my application P/Invokes to CreateDirectory (or mkdir on Linux), so that I can inspect the error code and detect collisions proactively.

@JonathanGilbert: Right, of course you need the temp name to include something random or unique to this thread (like the thread ID), not the same name as other threads of the same process, or other instances of the program, will use.  Unix rename is only atomic within the same filesystem, so normally you'd want to create it in the same directory as your move destination.  If that's /tmp then /tmp/xyz$PID could work

That's a convention that, if everybody is following it, guarantees uniqueness. But, if it's just your convention, someone else might come up with a completely independent xyz### convention and produce a collision. It's not terribly likely, but it could happen, and you can design things so that it can't happen.

@JonathanGilbert: Didn't see your reply earlier since you didn't @ notify me.  Yes, that's possible, especially with a malicious process trying to create collisions against a predictable format/pattern; that's why the POSIX mkdir system call returns an error if the directory already existed.  If you're doing this in a subdirectory where only your process should be doing stuff and untrusted users can't write it, that goes a long way.  But if you don't have that, then a CreateDirectory that doesn't distinguish between already existing or not isn't sufficient.  This answer doesn't cover that.

@PeterCordes Sure. The thing is, Windows and Linux both have this convention where the API that creates a directory will return an error if it already exists. Based on this, native code has an inherent, natural convention of "Generate a path, try to create it, repeat as needed" to get a directory you own. All apps are going to be doing this -- except apps written in .NET, because Directory.CreateDirectory doesn't work that way. Even Directory.CreateTempSubdirectory does that, though.

Incidentally, Directory.CreateTempSubdirectory can be used to get a directory created in the first place that you know you were the creator of, and then that directory can be moved into place with Directory.Move, which will fail if someone else happens to get there just before you. The race condition between Directory.Exists and creation is closed. So, this does provide a general solution to the problem. :-)

@rotabor See my preceding comment for a relevant thought that just occurred to me.
